# WordPress trims off the forward slash when import

Tags: htaccess, import, xml

I have an XML file with some posts to import to WordPress

But, when I import, it seems that WordPress takes off the forward slash from the permalink, so instead of showing the address like this:

```
http://localhost/site/man-clothes/jeans-pants/ripped/rock-style
```

WordPress take off the forward slash from the itens, e prints out like this:

```
http://localhost/site/man-clothesjeans-pantsrippedrock-style
```

But if I change the link to underscore insted of the forward slash, wordpress didn´t trims of the underscore and prints out the address like this:

```
http://localhost/site/man-clothes_jeans-pants_ripped_rock-style
```

Someone knows why the forward slash is getting cutoff.

My .htaccess is

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /votanalei/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /votanalei/index.php [L]
</IfModule> 
# END WordPress
```